# Qt Creator with Cmake

Tags: qt, build, cmake, qt-creator

I followed these instructions here : [Qt with CMake](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.8/creator-project-cmake.html)

so now I can build my project but the problem is, I can't see the project's sources and headers. I have just a CMakeLists.txt on the left and that's it. I don't understand how can I fix this. On Visual Studio, when I used CMake, all sources and headers of my project were appeared.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Qt Creator shows only files which are listed in your CMakeLists.txt as source files. Add them there and they will show up in the UI.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(MyProject)
add_executable(my_exe main.cpp)
```

Now main.cpp will be visible in the "Projects" pane in Qt Creator.